# control level of synthetic events from .with_span_events()?

Tags: rust, rust-tracing

I'm able to emit events using https://docs.rs/tracing-subscriber/latest/tracing_subscriber/fmt/struct.Layer.html#method.with_span_events, but they are created at TRACE level. Is there any way to cause these to be created at a different level?

Answer (score 0):

From https://docs.rs/tracing/latest/tracing/attr.instrument.html:

> Unless overridden, a span with the `INFO` level will be generated...

So you can change the generated span events' level by setting level argument of `#[instrument]` macro.

```rs
#[instrument(level = "debug")]
pub fn my_function() {
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The level is determined by the span's itself level, and [this is hardcoded and cannot be changed](https://docs.rs/tracing-subscriber/0.3.18/src/tracing_subscriber/fmt/fmt_layer.rs.html#790).

The level of the span can be set:

- If you are using the [`span!()`](https://docs.rs/tracing/latest/tracing/macro.span.html) macro, the first argument is the level. Or you can use one of the shortcut macros: [`trace_span!()`](https://docs.rs/tracing/latest/tracing/macro.trace_span.html) etc..
- If you are using [`#[instrument]`](https://docs.rs/tracing/latest/tracing/attr.instrument.html), you can pass a `level = "<level>"` argument to it.

Answer (score -3):

You can create events using the [event!](https://docs.rs/tracing/latest/tracing/macro.event.html) macro with the desired level specified, e.g.

```rust
event!(Level::ERROR, %error, "Received error");
```

Or even better you can use the [shorthand macros](https://docs.rs/tracing/latest/tracing/index.html#shorthand-macros) for each level

```rust
error!(%error, "Received error");
```

Comment: The event's created by `.with_span_events()` are created within tracing-subscriber itself, not by the user. So this doesn't help.